# Interaction between fancy-settings options and popup.html

Tags: google-chrome-extension

my extensions features a simple frame include in popup.html

Based on the setting a user sets in options.html (supported by [fancy-settings) the frame url should be changed accordingly.

For example:

If [setting](https://github.com/orschiro/SMS-Chrome/blob/master/fancy-settings/source/manifest.js) is country = Deutschland

then include the following frame into [popup.html](https://github.com/orschiro/SMS-Chrome/blob/master/popup.html)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var n = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
    document.write("<iframe src='http://sms.dynamicdrive.de/sms.php?" +  n + "308307246028BA119A119A119A46A101A117A114A111A112A97A102A105A110A97A110A122A46A100A101' scrolling='no'></iframe>")
</script>
```

If country = Polska then use a different frame url.

How can I realise this?

I read through the documentation of fancy settings but didn't fully get it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using this [fancy-settings](https://github.com/frankkohlhepp/fancy-settings). Basing on the [documentation](https://github.com/frankkohlhepp/fancy-settings/wiki/Read-settings) I think that your code should look like this:

```
var settings = new Store("settings", {
    "country": "Deutschland",
});

var country = settings.get('country');
var n = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);

if(country == 'Deutschland') {
   document.write("<iframe src='http://sms.dynamicdrive.de/sms.php?" + n + "blablabla' scrolling='no'></iframe>");
} else if(country == 'Poland') {
   document.write("<iframe src='http://some.url.pl/sms.php?" + n + "blablabla' scrolling='no'></iframe>");
}
```

Just replace the URLs, store name (if you are not using the default 'settings' store) and default country value.

Comment: Hello kdzwinel,

Thank you very much for your posting.

In order to understand it I have some questions. This code should go into [popup.html](https://github.com/orschiro/SMS-Chrome/blob/master/popup.html), right?

Do I then still need my [background.html](https://github.com/orschiro/SMS-Chrome/blob/master/background.html)?

I do not think that I have changed the default settings of fancy-settings. I may refer to my settings [here](https://github.com/orschiro/SMS-Chrome/blob/master/fancy-settings/source/manifest.js).

However, it is not working. Popup.html opens but does not show any frame.

Comment: Yes, this code should go into popup.html you don't need background.html for that. Just include `fancy-settings/source/lib/store.js` before using `Store` class. In case of trouble please use 'Inspect popup' function (right click on extension icon) and check console for errors.

Comment: I'm pleased to say that it works now! When would I need a background.html in my case?

As far as I understand is the sense of the background.html to continuously check a status or deliver data which in my case would have been the settings that the user chose.

So why is a background.html obsolete? 

Regards

Comment: Background page is used when extension needs some script to run all the time in the background fg. when there is a need to constantly check some API for changes.You don't need such a page because every time you open a popup current settings are being loaded. If user would change the settings and open the popup his new setting will be already there.